# How to separate two branches into two different branches

Tags: git, github, version-control

I know that subject probably doesn't make any sense, but let me explain.

I have been working on two problems at once, one in branch A and another in branch B.  Unfortunately, I was careless in making sure i was on the right branch when I did my changes and the two branches are now horribly intermingled: branch AB and branch BA.

I am looking for a way (hopefully in a GUI) to separate branch AB and BA back into branch A and branch B.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How many commits have you created since you started mixing A and B stuff?

Comment: Too many to actually cherry pick.  That was my first idea.

Comment: Also, do you have commits that both introduce changes related to A *and* changes related to B?

Comment: I don't know. I need to go through the code and make that determination.  I was hoping i could go step by step and separate the changes into the two separate branches

Comment: Git is good at merging stuff, but not at disentangling a mess. You're probably better off merging those two branches together, then then run interactive rebase on each one and edit commits in order to keep only changes related to the current branch. Unfortunately, I don't think you have any other choice but to do things manually.

Comment: Do you have a programmatic way to determine which commits belong to A versus B?  For instance, some identifying text in the commit message, or the files changed, or something.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have go through the code and separate it manually. Sucks but that's what i get for not being more careful.  Manually is the way to go it appears.  If there is an answer i would love to hear it but unfortunately i don't think there is.